# Как автоматически изменять цену при изменении/загрузке товара в 1с-битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Доброго времени суток
Необходимо при импорте товаров из 1С в 1с-битрикс перезаписывать цену `$arFields['PRICE']=$arFields['PRICE']/100*110;`, в init.php закинул событие (подобное нашел на форуме), но не цена не изменяется

```html
<?
AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate", Array("MyClass", "OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdateHandler"));

class MyClass
{
   function OnBeforePriceUpdateHandler($PRICE_ID, $arFields)
   {
      $db_price = CPrice::GetList(
         array(),
         array(
            "ID" => $PRICE_ID
         )
      );

      if($ar_price = $db_price->Fetch())
      {
         if($ar_price['PRICE'] != $arFields['PRICE'])
         {
            $arFields['PRICE']=$arFields['PRICE']/100*110;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению при импорте не происходит событие изменения элемента. Есть событие `OnSuccessCatalogImport1C`, которое возникает при окончании одного шага импорта — и можно на него повесить поиск обновлённых товаров и вызывать для них Вашу функцию.

```
AddEventHandler('catalog', 'OnSuccessCatalogImport1C', 'OnBeforeAllPriceUpdateHandler');
```